# Exposed port not actually exposed? - RHEL7 running RHEL7 docker image

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, rhel, rhel7

I am having trouble **contacting an RHEL 7 docker container running in RHEL 7**. The problem arises **from other computers in the same network**. **The host can contact its own flask server running in its docker container**. The container is bare-metals, without `firewalld` or `iptables`.

I have `docker-compose` connecting a `mysql:latest` image and the bare-metals `rhel7` running python flask. I have a mysql server running on the same RHEL 7 host, and I can `nc` it perfectly well from another computer in the same network. I have no information on how the specific rhel image was built, and it's closed source, so I have to work around that, however, the `mysql` image is from `registry.access.redhat.com`.

### Some outputs

Some private information is replaced by `???`

#### Docker info

```
$ docker info
Containers: 22
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 20
Images: 67
Server Version: 1.12.6
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-253:1-117440691-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 13.65 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 89.54 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 15.32 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.132 GB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: true
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: true
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: ???
 WARNING: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` to specify a custom block storage device.
 Metadata loop file: ???
 Library Version: 1.02.140-RHEL7 (2017-05-03)
Logging Driver: journald
Cgroup Driver: systemd
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge null host overlay
 Authorization: rhel-push-plugin
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: docker-runc runc
Default Runtime: docker-runc
Security Options: seccomp selinux
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-693.1.1.el7.x86_64
Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.4 (Maipo)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
Number of Docker Hooks: 3
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 11.58 GiB
Name: ???
ID: ???
Docker Root Dir: ???
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Http Proxy: http://???.com:82
Https Proxy: http://???.com:82
Registry: https://???.com/v1/
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Registries: ???.com (secure), registry.access.redhat.com (secure), docker.io (secure)
```

#### Running docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
db053a1518e3        ???_server         "/usr/bin/python Laun"   54 minutes ago      Up 54 minutes       0.0.0.0:8087->8087/tcp   ???_server_1
69d512050bb9        ???_db             "docker-entrypoint.sh"   54 minutes ago      Up 54 minutes       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   ???_db_1
```

#### Running netstat

For mysql:

```
 $ sudo netstat -anp | grep 3306
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      30338/docker-proxy-
```

For flask:

```
$ sudo netstat -anp | grep 8087
tcp6       0      0 :::8087                 :::*                    LISTEN      30454/docker-proxy- 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     368087   21392/dockerd-curre  /var/run/docker.sock
```

### Why I think it's the container's fault - using nc/telnet

The mysql container is using ubuntu, I believe, which likely has different permissioning than RHEL. The `nc` from another computer in the same network gives me:

```
$ nc 100.71.26.29 3306
J5.7.19{)EOm3ÿÿÁQZBTm%KM-mysql_native_password
```

Which isn't saying *much* but at least we know it's running.

Now, I created a test docker image from the same base image, and installed `nc`. I ran the following:

```
$  nc -l 8088
hello world!
```

The `hello world!` was from my telnet connection from my host:

```
$ telnet localhost 8088
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
hello world!
^]
telnet> Connection closed.
```

**This means it worked on the same machine.**

Now, let's try it on **separate machines.**

The separate machine **can't connect:**

```
$ telnet 100.71.26.29 8088
Trying 100.71.26.29... # hangs forever
telnet: connect to address 100.71.26.29: Connection timed out
```

### Why I think it's the container's fault - using curl

Running curl in localhost for the specific port gives me exactly what I want for the flask server:

```
$ curl localhost:8087


                ... A lot of HTML ...
                <div>
                    <input id = "get-csv" type = "submit" class = "custom-button">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Running curl INSIDE docker by executing:

```
$ docker exec -it server:latest /bin/bash
...
docker$ curl localhost:8087


                ... A lot of HTML ...
                <div>
                    <input id = "get-csv" type = "submit" class = "custom-button">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**But running curl from another computer fails:**

```
$ curl 100.71.26.29:8087 # hangs for like 2 minutes:

<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big>Network Error (tcp_error)</big>
<BR>
<BR>
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica" SIZE=2>
<BR>
For assistance, contact your network support team.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</blockquote>
</FONT>
</BODY></HTML>
```

---

So does anyone have any thoughts on what's going on exactly here? Thanks!

Comment: Your test with `nc` doesn't do anything useful.  A webserver doesn't respond until you send it a request (try, e.g., `nc www.google.com 80`; it will "hang and never respond", also). What happens if you use `curl` against `100.71.26.29:8087`? It seems like an obvious test (you're already using `curl` for other tests!) but it seems to be missing.

Comment: @larsks Thanks for the comment about nc - you're right :o, I'll include a separate test case for nc. For the curl situation, I have that exactly at the bottom of the post :)

Comment: @larsks just updated the nc example to use telnet for a dummy echo program. Doesn't work on a separate computer.

Comment: The problem is related to your proxy. You are proxying your outgoing traffic, and i believe that is not allowing you to process the incoming traffic. Remove proxies on both the side, and try again